# Is there Bayesian search theory about search through the space of Bayesian models?

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, nonparametric-bayes

Consider we start with a specific Bayesian model, say an infinite mixture model with a Dirichlet Process as a prior. I know there are wildly many variants on this theme, from the Hierarchical Dirichlet Process, the Nested Dirichlet Process, the Transformed Dirichlet Process and other dependent versions that try to incorporate spatial or temporal dependencies. And then we have the "mirror world" with the Beta Process and its extensions.

Continuously in this field a scientists rewrites one of the priors into a process and corresponding hyperprior(s), preferably using some dining metaphor. And voila, another paper.

Did someone attempt to search through this space? I admit it is huge. It is likely however that if this search is done properly we do not need to recompute everything all the time. If I have a vat with marbles that turn out all to be blue, and now I pick a marble from another vat, which turns out to be red, it is reasonable to have some prior corresponding to this event. It can be governed by the prior on the "color level", or on the more abstract level of "uniformity".

The search through the "space of priors", seems to me the most interesting one in the world of Bayesians... Some pointers to work in this direction would be great!